# SQL profile name error when executing job

Tags: sql, sql-server, job-scheduling

I'm trying to make a scheduled job, so that on the day 25 of every month it sends an e-mail with some information. The code I have right now is:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
          @profile_name = 'Main DB Mail profile',
          @recipients = 'myemail@mydomain.net',
          @subject = 'PG25',
          @query = N'SELECT CONVERT(date, docdata), adoc, nome, etotal, aprovado FROM fo
                     WHERE aprovado LIKE "0" 
                       AND pdata BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 25)',
          @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
          @query_attachment_filename = 'results.txt'
```

but when I execute this code I get this error:

> Msg 14607, Level 16, State 1, Procedure msdb.dbo.sysmail_verify_profile_sp, Line 42 [Batch Start Line 5]
>   Profile name is not valid

Any thoughts on how I can get this to work?

Comment: as the error message stated clearly. The profile is not valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that profile name you are calling has to exist in `Database Mail`. In order to check, do the following:

- Expand Management within your instance;
- Then, right click and **Configure Database Mail**;
- After this, if you already have a profile defined, you can choose the 4th option to check the profile name. Otherwise, you need to define a new one (careful on the profile name you choose because it has to match to the one you're calling);

[image]

[image]

Comment: somenthing happened, maybe i had the profile name wrong, don't really know. either way, now i get this magical error:

Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.

Comment: I saw that you've solve your initial error. Please accept the answer.